# create and use nested master page in aspx page as module for sharepoint 2013 using visual studio 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, master-page, aspx, module

I have added one aspx page by taking Module in Visual Studio. I have to do something like;

1. I have to show messages for error and successful completion of the task i.e. Item added successfully
2. I have to modify header and footer
   for that purpose I have to add nested master page in my aspx page with default master

So a structure like:

Master page -> Child master page -> Content of aspx page

How should I proceed? Please guide me.